# Custom Bar Styles & Progress

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2013

I've created a number of custom bar styles that are linked to a custom Text30 field, to show the basic health of the project (Green, Yellow, Red).

(based on:  http://www.tacticalprojectmanagement.com/microsoft-project-dashboard-tutorial/#comment-265)

The only problem is that I cannot get the progress bars to show up within the custom bar styles.

My gut tells me the answer is simple, but it escapes me.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the progress bar line and paste 2 times below the custom bars you've created.  On the second Progress bar, change the name and change the Show For....Tasks to Flag1,Flag2,Flag3.

[image]